# What is the proper use of "right the way along"?

Tags: idioms, british-english, word-usage

I've heard the idiom "right the way along" used many times in British literature and video, however, I'm slightly unclear as to what it means.

It seems, at first glance, to be a British variant on "move it along" or "moving right along" or some such, but there are counterexamples. One of which is in [a Monty Python sketch](http://youtu.be/f1oMhMwUbgc?t=2m2s), where "right the way along" is used to mean something slightly different. This and other odd uses lead me to question the intended meaning of the phrase.

What is the etymology and proper use/application for "right the way along"?

Comment: In the [examples I see](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right+the+way+along&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) it means "All the way along"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mplungjan is correct -- "right the way along" (and variants such as "right the way up" or "right the way down") simply means "all the way along".  "right" in the sense of "complete" or "completely" is fairly common, especially in British English.